# Required help in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have this below json data.

```
[{"start_date":"2014-06-27","count":"21","value":"134"},{"start_date":"2014-06-28","count":"17","value":"120"},{"start_date":"2014-06-29","count":"21","value":"138"},{"start_date":"2014-06-30","count":"9","value":"121"},{"start_date":"2014-07-01","count":"12","value":"112"},{"start_date":"2014-07-02","count":"19","value":"132"}]
```

I trying to plot this a line chart using highcharts.

I wanted to convert my data to something like this.

```
[{
   name: "count",
   data: [21, 17 .......]
},{
  name: "value",
  data: [134, 120, .......]
}]
```

How can I format my data like that using jquery?

I use AJAX to get that data from a database.

Any help will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) Init an empty structure like the desired, but without data. b) Loop through the source data and populate the target object one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array = [{"start_date":"2014-06-27","count":"21","value":"134"},{"start_date":"2014-06-28","count":"17","value":"120"},{"start_date":"2014-06-29","count":"21","value":"138"},{"start_date":"2014-06-30","count":"9","value":"121"},{"start_date":"2014-07-01","count":"12","value":"112"},{"start_date":"2014-07-02","count":"19","value":"132"}]

var chartOptions = [];
var countData = {name: "count", data: []};
var valueData = {name: "value", data: []};

array.forEach(function(value, index){
  countData.data.push(value.count);
  valueData.data.push(value.value);
});

chartOptions.push(countData);
chartOptions.push(valueData);
```

Answer (score 1):

**USE**

```
var res= YOUR JSON DATA
var data=$.parseJSON(res);
var count= new Array();
var val=new Array();
$(data).each(function(i,u){
    count.push(u.count);
    val.push(u.value);
});

now you can use 

[{
   name: "count",
   data: count
},{
  name: "value",
  data: val
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build the JSON structure required by highcharts server side, before returning it in the AJAX call. There simply adding it directly to highcharts.

This will be more efficient then letting the users browser make the formating.